# Render a react.js component with document.write() inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a component which uses `document.write()` inside, as I have to convert a json string to HTML. The problem I face is that when doing this the component only renders what is inside the `document.write()`.

The code is the following:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div className="main-wrapper">
        <Link className="back-home" to="/">
          All news
        </Link>
        {this.state.articles.map(articulo => {
          console.log(articulo.content.rendered);
          return (
            <article className="article-wrapper" key={articulo.id}>
              <h1>{document.write(articulo.title.rendered)}</h1>
              <span className="article-date">
                {this.dameFecha(articulo.date)}
              </span>
              <img
                className="article-image"
                src={
                  articulo.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.small
                    .source_url
                }
              />
              <div className="article-content">
                {document.write(articulo.content.rendered)}
              </div>
            </article>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

None of the elements are shown this way. I have already tried to put inside the `document.write()` all the elements, but React doesn't allow to do that. I mean doing this:

```
render() {
  return (document.write(/* all the code */))
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) to render your string of HTML:

```
<h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: articulo.title.rendered }} />
```

Comment: Thanks again! Works fine, I will validate your answer in 5 minutes!